# Selenium IDE not capturing the popup/ Alerts

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-ide, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium IDE to record the commands. I need to test the red rout for login screen. But Selenium is not recognizing the alert coming from the application. Highlighted in bold alert message is not captured by the selenium IDE.

```
selenium.open("http://192.168.132.244:8080/SampleApp/");
assertEquals("SampleApp", selenium.getTitle());
selenium.type("name=userame", "NoUser");          --USER NAME
selenium.type("name=password", "Password1"); --Password
selenium.click("css=input[type=\"image\"]"); --Login button
selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
```

> **Please enter correct Username and Password.**  -- Alert message

```
assertEquals("SampleApp", selenium.getTitle());
```

Please help me out completing this selenium...

Answer (score 0):

Try out this 1

```
assertEquals("Please enter correct Username and Password.", selenium.getAlert());
```

Let me know whether working or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rohit. I tried the above code but it is not able to capture the Alert. I am getting the following error message. `No alerts`

Comment: when you click on login button, there is alert for incorrect username and password on site..right??if yes then used above code right after click event of login button

Comment: if i am not wrong then in selenium IDE you get commands like assertAlert | Please enter correct Username and Password.

Comment: Yes Rohit, as per Thoughtworks selenium is not capable of capturing the java scripts Alert messages. (http://thoughtstoblog.blogspot.in/2009/09/selenium-alert-and-confirm-in-pages.html 
)

Comment: You could use  verify/assertAlert to check presence of alert on page. Since selenium  cannot click on “Ok” button on js alert window, the alert itself does  not appear on page when this check is carried out.

Answer (score 0):

I've also had success with waitForAlert versus an assert or verify, but as with all your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

USe this command hope this will help you 
`<tr>
    <td>storeAlert</td>
    <td>a</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`
`<tr>
    <td>echo</td>
    <td>${a}</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>`